# Insufficient storage error

Tags: android

I am getting an insufficient storage error in android.
I have about 100MB of data in my res/raw folder.Is this the reason.
PLease anyone give me a solution.
I created another AVD 2 but its not working
the error is still coming
PLease help me
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your res/raw folder will be put onto the phones internal memory and this space is very limited. 100Mb for an application is rediculous size ([see here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android%20Market/thread?tid=719c8415f46d3e0d&hl=en)).

The android market has an apk file size limit (can't find documentation for this) but from reference above 45Mb is too large. Also 100Mb over 3G would take forever...

If you really need the files you should consider having your app download the resources it needs to the SD card.

Comment: what I have to do store my resources in the SD card

Comment: Well your whole application will get stored in the phones internal memory, so you will need to download them separately. This means writing some (or copying) download code that will be ran on the first use of the app. 100Mb is still crazy, what are the files?

Answer (score 1):

I have recently had this problem with a 500K apk and over 25MB of storage available on internal. I trued everything i could think of, reseting phone/ddms etc.

No JOY.

I eventually found out that it was the **NAME of my project** (and thus the name of the APK to install!!) It was either too long (16chr)... or it was because it had swedish letters in it (öäå).

I shortened project name and replaced with a and o and it worked perfectly!! So definately could be one reason why you are getting this.